# What is causing c++ function signature to be different?

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling

Our build machine is set up with an earlier version of Android NDK. Most of our code is built on this machine and the final Android image is created.

My development machine uses the latest version of Android NDK.

I am creating a static library from my C++ code on my development machine and copy it over to the build machine for final linking.

The problem is that the compiler on the two machines seem to differ on name mangling.

For example, for std::string, my dev machine produces this signature:

```
 std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, ...>
```

However, on the build machine, the expected signature is:

```
 std::__1::basic_string<char, ...>
```

I am trying to figure out if the android-gcc compiler using a different name-mangling scheme or if stl files themselves are different. If it is the first case, is there a way to enforce a different name-mangling scheme. Thanks.

Comment: Why this is a problem? You are worrying on implementation detail of standard library. This is not name mangling! Name mangling is transform `std::__1::basic_string....` and information about types of arguments (to enable overloading) into sequence of characters containing only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: You can not do this: `creating a static library from my C++ code on my development machine and copy it over to the build machine for final linking.` There are no guarantees of ABI compatibility between different toolchains, so you have to build all your C++ code using the same toolchain. You have to either make sure your dev machine toolchain matches build machine, or, better, make your library build as a part of the final build.

Comment: @MarekR, well, OP explains exactly why it is a problem for them.

Comment: But this is not name mangling issue.

Comment: @MarekR it is, at least in some sense - at leasts it manifests itself as a mangling issue, although mangling is only part of the ABI.

Comment: Difference is result of different target platform and different implementation of standard library for it. Most probably on local machine he builds for emulator/simulator and build machine is builds for target platform. This should not have impact on how code works. That is why I ask "why this is a problem?".

Comment: @MarekR and OP explicitly explains why it is a problem for them: `I am creating a static library from my C++ code on my development machine and copy it over to the build machine for final linking.` OP is doing something which is bound to fail, but you should not be asking them "why is it a problem", since OP explained why such a behavior is an obstacle.

Comment: SergeyA. Can you please explain why there is "no guarantee" of ABI compatibility? The ABI is arm. Two NDKs may have different compiler versions. However, ultimately they produce arm-compatible instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no name mangling going on here. There seems to be two different standard libraries in use, one defines `basic_string` in an internal namespace called `__ndk1`, the other one in `__1`. This is basically an implementation detail. Make sure to use the same compiler and standard library implementation for these to match.

P.S. [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is not a function, but a class template.